# upon selection of any selectItems value the related record like address will be displayed

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

jsf adf....

My code in adf jsf.
this code creates a choice list form the model....and I want that if user selects the perticular customer id from the select list the related address will be displayed in the next line. any idea and solution how to add or bind data control(for address attribute) for  such that when the select item vales from the select list generated from the binded model(id attribute only) is selected then the related adrress will get displayed.

```
<af:selectOneChoice label="#{bindings.InvView1.label}" id="soc1"
binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_inv.soc1}"
value="#{bindings.InvView1.inputValue}"
required="#{bindings.InvView1.hints.mandatory}">

<f:selectItems value="#{bindings.InvView1.items}" id="si2"
binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_inv.si2}" />

</af:selectOneChoice>
</af:selectOneChoice>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bean with a setter (customer ID) that gets activated upton customer selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a navigation list.
Like this:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/the_navigation_list_select_som